# Staggered Layout in CSS

Tags: css, styled-components

I don't know if "staggered" is the correct way to call this layout but I'm trying to do this:

[image]

Any idea how to make the separation between boxes 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { services } from "./data";

const StyleCards = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
`;
const StyleCard = styled.div``;

const StyleImg = styled.img``;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyleCards>
      {services.map((service) => (
        <StyleCard key={service.name}>
          <StyleImg src={service.img} />
          <p>{service.name}</p>
          <p>{service.description}</p>
        </StyleCard>
      ))}
    </StyleCards>
  );
}
```

Here is a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-card-css-5k4xh?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: We need your code here, as a runnable snippet. **You are required to post all relevant parts of the code right in your question (always)**, only then are external code representations acceptable. You should also guarantee the external references don't change over time or become unavailable.

Comment: There isn't enough information here for us to answer the question. What is the amount of staggering (offset) that is required? For example if there is a very long description what happens compared to if there is a very short description?

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth , you're right I need to be more clear The offset is 75px.  No matter the length description it should always be 75px.

Comment: @connexo I updated the thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that result with the `:nth-child` selector and add a margin top to each component

```
    .Card:nth-child(2n) {
       margin-top: 75px;
    }
```

Since you're using styled-components you can do

```
const StyleCard = styled.div`
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  &:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-top: 75px;
  }
`;
```

Comment: it's working, thanks!